# Spring choose property source by a combination of profiles

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, spring-annotations

I have multiple environments driven by Spring profiles, such as `application-int.yml`, `application-dev.yml` etc with similar content:

- `application-int.yml`

  ```
  ws:
     endpoint: http://my-soap-int-endpoint.com/
     mock: http://my-soap-int-mock-endpoint.com/
  ```
- `application-dev.yml`

  ```
  ws:
    endpoint: http://my-soap-dev-endpoint.com/
    mock: http://my-soap-dev-mock-endpoint.com/
  ```

My goal is to use the following property based on **both** the environment name **and** whether the `mock` profile is included:

- `ws.endpoint` from `application-dev.yml` for `dev` profiles
- `ws.endpoint` from `application-int.yml` for `int` profiles
- `ws.mock` from `application-dev.yml` for `dev mock` profiles
- `ws.mock` from `application-int.yml` for `int mock` profiles

I need to parse that value into a single variable `url`:

```
@Configuration
public class SoapConfiguration {

    @Value("???")                  // based on 2 properties
    private String wsUrl;
}
```

I would like to avoid complicated hierarchy of abstract configuration classes *only* based on `@Profile`. Moreover, I need to keep to keep *both* variables (mock and non-mock) in a common propery file.

Is there a nice way that is both readable and maintainable?

Comment: Could you provide some more context, this seems like a very complicated setup - what does it mean to have an environment _and_ a paired mock environment?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I need 2 different SOAP service endpoints for **each** environment switchable by an additional profile. The reason is, let's say, we can call the non-mocked service only limited times, therefore we need an additional endpoint which can be called without limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `wsUrl` in constructor. It's not so elegant solution but it works.
Inject `Environment` bean to your `SoapConfiguration` and check is `mock` profile active.
Code example:

```
@Configuration
public class SoapConfiguration {
    private final String wsUrl;

    public SoapConfiguration(Environment environment) {
        if (Arrays.asList(environment.getActiveProfiles()).contains("mock")) {
            this.wsUrl = environment.getProperty("ws.mock");
        } else {
            this.wsUrl = environment.getProperty("ws.endpoint");
        }
    }
}
```